# C# report from SQL query

Tags: sql, view, report

This is my first time even thinking about doing this and as expected it went wrong. 
I found this chunk of code on google and edited it for my needs.
Still it does not give any info on the Report Viewer except the error:

> The source of the report definition has not been specified.

```
string strConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\EvidencijaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM T_Plate");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

            da.Fill(ds, "DataSet1");

            rvPlate.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            rvPlate.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            rvPlate.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables[0]));
            rvPlate.LocalReport.Refresh();
            rvPlate.RefreshReport();
```

Edit:
I added

```
rvPlate.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "IzvestajPlata.rdlc";
```

line and created IzvestajPlate.rdlc. Now it seems like code is working but nothing is outputted in the report viewer.

Edit2:
After adding

```
foreach (DataTable thisTable in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in thisTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in thisTable.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I get an output:

> 1
>   Intesa1
>   111111
>   8800
>   2
>   Intesa2
>   222222
>   17600
>   3
>   Intesa3
>   333333
>   18400

So the dataset isn't empty just not sending values to the report viewer...
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

you haven't supplied the embedded resource. add the following line to your code:

```
rvPlate.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourReport.rdlc";
```

Comment: An error occurred during local report processing. The report definition for report 'IzvestajPlate'  has not been specified. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Hmm I managed to solve that error but now I don't get any data in DGV :S

Comment: Make sure you have data in your dataset. @Morsus

Comment: Shouldn't the data be selected with the query. The table isn't empty.

Comment: have you supplied the datasetname of your Table in rdlc designer ?